# differentiating $\phi(u,t)=e^{(iu^T\hat{x_t}-\frac{1}{2}u^TP_tu)} w.r.t$ t?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Here $\phi(u,t)=E\{e^{iut}\} $ is a characteristic function, $x_t$ is Gaussian. Differentiating $\phi(u,t)=e^{(iu^T\hat{x_t}-\frac{1}{2}u^TP_tu)}$ w.r.t t the result is $\phi_u=\phi[i\hat{x}_t-P_tu]$

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I don't know stochastic calculus, but I guess it is the esparance derivative $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathbb{E}[\phi]}{\partial t}$ (esperance on all possible random/stochastic processes) your are calculating

Comment: to calculate ${\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}}$